# How do I filter Django models to only include models that appear in a child (with a ForeignKey) table?

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

I have these two Django models:

```
class Animals(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField(unique=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'animals'

class AnimalSounds(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    sound = models.TextField(unique=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'animal_sounds'
```

Now my SQL query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE animals.id IN (
    SELECT animal_id FROM animal_sounds
)
```

How would I do this using Django models? Something like this conceptually:

```
Animals.objects.filter(id__in=AnimalSounds.objects.all('ids'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there is at least one `AnimalSound` related with:

```
Animal.objects.filter(animalsounds__isnull=False).distinct()
```

This will perform a query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT animal.*
FROM animal AS ani
JOIN animalsounds AS ans ON ans.animal_id = ani.id
```

Or you can use your approach with:

```
Animals.objects.filter(
    id__in=AnimalSounds.objects.values('animal_id', flat=True)
)
```

But I prefer the former since it is more declarative and shorter.

**EDIT**: If you want to select *all* `Animal`s that have a related `AnimalSounds` object where `sound` is `'woof'`, you can write it like:

```
# animals that produce woof (and perhaps other sounds)
Animal.objects.filter(animalsounds__sound='woof').distinct()
```

Comment: Awesome that works. Now how about if I wanted to do this query:

    ```SELECT * FROM animals WHERE animals.id IN (
        SELECT animal_id FROM animal_sounds WHERE sound = 'woof'
    )```

Is that possible?

Comment: @superdee: then you add an extra element to the filter `animalsounds__sound='woof'`